# Windows 8 Application Development for Phone,Desktop and Tablets

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows

I am about to start the development of an Windows 8 app. The app is supposes to run in phone, tablet and desktop. I went through lot of docs in msdn sites and this is what I understood from them.

1. There is no way to create one project which supports both phone and (tablet,desktop).
2. User can create a Portable class library project and put all the reusable code into it and add it as reference to the actual projects.
3. create one project for windows phone and one project for window store app(create using dev account)

Please correct me if I am wrong and also let me know if there is any other way of doing it. Also I understand like the window store app will work for both tablet and desktop whereas windows phone app works only in phones and not in tablet.Is it right?

Comment: Yes all your 3 points are correct. And yes windows store apps work on both tablets and desktop. WP apps only work in WP.

Answer (score 0):

Windows tablet comes in two flavours, Windows Pro and Windows RT.

Will the desktop store app work on both the tablets ?

is there different development environment for different category of tablets?

Comment: Pls add your query in new question.